# Python Line Comparison

Tags: python, regex, hash, comparison

I have a directory with subdirectories full of files that all contain the line :

```
VERSION "1.0"  # THAT NUMBER VARIES.
```

So one file as an example of the content would read :

```
 #comments about what the file program does
 #
 #

 #ifndefine _AWS_THIS_READS_STUFF_H
 #define _AWS_THIS_READS_STUFF_H

 #define AWS_THIS_READS_STUFF_VERSION "1.2" <---this is the line I want 
                                            #to compare that is in all
```

Then the read of the file would be some long program in C that is written.

I used the number to identify when I have made changes. I need to make something in Python that identifies if the numbers before the decimal and after the decimal all match within a directory, since there are hundreds of files.

```
import glob
import sys
import re
import filecmp
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import dropwhile

myfiles = glob.glob('*.h')
for filename in myfiles: 
print(filename) #this prints all of the file names

def all_same(patt):
    r = re.compile('#define\s+([_A-Z]+)_VERSION\s+("\d+\.\d+")$') #REGEX to find
    files = glob.glob(patt)
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for file in files:
        with open(file) as f:
            version = r.search(next(dropwhile(lambda x: "VERSION" not in x, f)))
            d[version].append(file) #search for VERSION LINE
return d
```

and when it is run in my command prompt it prints nothing out.

ALSO TRIED THIS! - I got it to print out the file and the "0.0" number but now I need to compare!

```
myfiles = glob.glob('*.h') #reads in all files ending in .h
for file in myfiles:
    for line in open(file):
        line = line.rstrip()
        if re.search('VERSION\s+("\d+\.\d+")$', line):
            list = re.findall("\d+\.\d+" , line)
            list.append(file)
            print(list)
            #print (list + ' : ' + root + "/" + myfile)
    with open(file) as f:
        version = re.findall('VERSION\s+("\d+\.\d+")$', file)
        version = re.search(next(dropwhile(lambda x: "VERSION" not in x, f)))
        print(version)
```

Just need to figure out how to compare numbers in the list of "0.0" - Once again, before decimal and after)

Comment: Have you actually *tried* anything?

Comment: How about `grep VERSION *.h | sort -u`?

Comment: Ok, so you are searching the file content itself? Are all the version lines at the start?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have tried a lot,I have tried filecmp and I have tried hashing but I am not fluent when it comes to python as I usually work with JavaScripts. But Yes, all of the files contain VERSION and then some number Padriac but the numbers do vary, always a number then decimal then another number. Also Sven thank you, I will look into that as well.

Comment: So please give a [mcve] of your code and a specific error.

Comment: @Girls.Gone.Wired, is it the first line in the file?

Comment: No its the not the first line, it is however in the heading. I know how to find the line using regex. @jonrsharpe I am adding it now.

Comment: @Girls.Gone.Wired, cmp takes two files to compare, can the line appear anywhere or is it always at the beginning? Also do you stop if you encounter any different number or are you trying to find every unique number?

Comment: I though I was using it wrong, thank you, I had read an instance where it was two directories. Mine is one with many files. The lines are always around or before line 10. If the lines are different I was hoping to make it print out the file name. In most cases the numbers should be the same unless I forgot to edit one.

Comment: I think you grouping by version is the best approach

Comment: @SvenMarnach can you give me an example or help me with where to start with grep?

Comment: @Girls.Gone.Wired If you are on a Unix-like OS (basically any OS but Windows), you should be able to get a sorted list of versions by calling something like `grep -h VERSION *.h | sort -u` in the shell.  You might need to adapt for varying spacing etc.  The idea is to use grep to exract the lines containing the version numbers, sort them, and only print the unique ones, so if all files have the same verison, you'll get only a single line of output, otherwise multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

If your version line is header of each file you could pull the first returned from `iglob` and compare that line to the rest with `all`:

```
import glob
import re
from collections import defaultdict
def all_same(patt):
    r = re.compile("VERSION\s+(\d+\.\d+)")
    files = glob.iglob(patt)
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for file in files:
        with open(file) as f:
            version = r.search(next(dropwhile(lambda x: "VERSION" not in x, f)))
            d[version].append(file)
    return d
```

If you actually want to the names of all the files with different version numbers, I would find the VERSION line in each file and group by the version number in a dict using the version number as the key and appending the file names as the values:

```
import glob
import re
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import dropwhile
def all_same(path):
    r = re.compile("VERSION\s+(\d+\.\d+)")
    files = glob.iglob(path)
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for file in files:
        with open(file) as f:
            version = r.search(next(dropwhile(lambda x: "VERSION" not in x, f))).group()
            d[version].append(file)
    return d
```

Comment: @Girls.Gone.Wired, the last code will give you a dict where all files with common version numbers are grouped together, if you didn't group you would be doing `O(n^2)` comparisions

Comment: this doesn't seem to working any suggestions? I think the dict was definitely the best way to approach it after some research. I cant seem to get it to print anything out except all of the file names.

Comment: for the version = should it say "VERSION?" because all of the files say that.

Comment: add what your input looks like to your question

Comment: Okay, I added it. It pretty much is very similar to what you had. When I run it in my command prompt it accepts it, but it doesn't print anything out. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Girls.Gone.Wired, sorry, I meant what the data looks like in your file

Comment: I have made changes to the original post with an example of what the files would say @Padraic Cunningham

Comment: @Girls.Gone.Wired,  I made a couple of little changes, run the last function passing in the path to the directory

Comment: It still won't print anything out... below my code is what I tried as well after tinkering a bit, it still doesn't print though.

Comment: You need to use the dict returned from the function